# How to import google_maps in geolocation-python

Tags: python, geolocation

I've instaled geolocation-python

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geolocation-python/0.2.0

```
pip install geolocation-python
```

And I'm trying to follow the example, but at the first line:

```
from geolocation.google_maps import GoogleMaps
```

I get an error:

```
No module named google_maps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
from geolocation.main import GoogleMaps
```

instead. It worked for me.

See here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geolocation-python/0.2.2